# How can I create a "Proof of Theorem x.xx" header for a proof environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

In many papers in mathematics, the author states a theorem in somewhere and adds some explanations and perhaps some lemmas and later starts the proof with a phrase like "Proof of Theorem x.xx" (x's stand for some numbers). The only format I am aware for starting and ending a proof is as follows:

```
\begin{proof}

\end{proof}
```

This format is good when I start the proof immediately after stating theorems (propositions etc). So my question is:

> How can I start the proof later with a phrase like "Proof of Theorem x.xx"?

P.S. I am not sure about the tags I have used. Please, modify them if you know better tags.

Comment: What are you using to create your `theorem` and `proof` environments?

Comment: I wrote how I create my proofs. I create theorems with similar commands. Except I add a label after  begin;  \begin{theorem} \label{thm:somelabel}  ... the statement of the theorem ... \end{theorem}

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Assuming you're using a package such as `amsthm`, you could proceed as follows: Assign a `\label` to the theorem, and then cross-reference it via a `\ref` statement at the start of the associated `proof` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] \label{thm:neat}
$a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:neat}]
(state your proof here)
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: For comparison, here's the output of the same MWE (minus the filler text) if you were to use the `ntheorem` package. (Observe that `ntheorem` doesn't automatically place a QED symbol at the end of a `proof` environment.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{empty}
\newtheorem{refproof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] \label{thm:neat}
$a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{refproof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:neat}]
(state your proof here)
\end{refproof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you It's exactly the answer I was looking for. I assume that I can write any thing instead of "proof of Theorem", for example "the second part of the proof of Theorem", and so on.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh - You could definitely have both `\begin{proof}[First part of the proof of Theorem \ref{thm:neat}]`... and, later on, `\begin{proof}[Second part of the proof of Theorem \ref{thm:neat}].... Of course, you'll have to replace `thm:neat` with the actual label of the theorem in question.

Comment: I get the error "No counter 'Theorem' defined. \begin{theorem}[" when I try to implement your first code.

Comment: @sequence - Does your code feature an instruction such as `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` (as is the case in the answer I provided above)?

Comment: Yes, it does. @Mico

Comment: @sequence - The code I posted above more than seven years ago compiled without errors back then, *and it still compiles fine*. (I just checked!) Your document's code must differ materially from mine. Unfortunately, you appear to be unwilling to provide usable information about your LaTeX code and, instead, appear to think it suffices to provide some cryptic error message. I'm very sorry to have to inform you that I've never been any good at solving riddles. My abject apologies.

Comment: I would like to show you my code but the structure is exactly as what you wrote in your post. I put the `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` part before the `\begin{document}` tag, and the rest of the code from your post is after the `\begin{document}` tag, that is in the body of the document. Anyway, I've tried it in an empty file and it seems to compile. I don't understand what's wrong, but will have to debug this issue further... Thanks for your attention. @Mico

Comment: @sequence - The only idea I can add is to mention that LaTeX is case-sensitive. Hence, `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` and `\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}`, or `\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] ` and `\begin{Theorem}[Pythagoras]`, are not the same to LaTeX.