# Creating "Proof of Theorem X" Using the LLNCS Document Class

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, lncs

I have the following working example.

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:ex}
A very important result.
\end{theorem}

Some comments here \ldots

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:ex}]
It follows by inspection.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

This produces "Proof (Proof of Theorem 1)." as opposed to just "Proof of Theorem 1." - I was trying to mimic the solution here [How can I create a "Proof of Theorem x.xx" header for a proof environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135267/how-can-i-create-a-proof-of-theorem-x-xx-header-for-a-proof-environment), which does not appear to work with the LLNCS class. What's the simplest way to do this? I am trying to avoid using many additional packages, as instructed by the conference.

Edit: In my paper, I also have things like "Theorem 1 (Bob [2]).", which I would like to keep as is... so I need to make sure that the solution proposed does not effect such things.

Answer (score 5):

When there is an optional argument, the header (label) of unnumbered theorem-style environments is defined by the `\@Opargbegintheorem` macro.

Add:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@Opargbegintheorem}[4]{%
  #4\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep{#3#2\@thmcounterend}]}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@Opargbegintheorem}[4]{%
  #4\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep{#3#2\@thmcounterend}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:ex}
  A very important result.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Bob]
  Another very important result.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Clear.\qed
\end{proof}

Some comments here \ldots

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:ex}]
  It follows by inspection.\qed
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the definition of `\proof` (which is executed by `\begin{proof}`) to look for an optional argument and change the value of `\proofname` accordingly.

```
\documentclass[orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

%% avoid the silly redefinition done by llncs
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

%% change proof to accept the optional argument
\let\llncsproof\proof
\renewcommand{\proof}[1][]{%
  \ifx!#1!\else\renewcommand{\proofname}{#1}\fi
  \llncsproof
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:ex}
A very important result.
\end{theorem}

Some comments here \ldots

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:ex}]
It follows by inspection.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\proofname` is local to the environment; it will affect also nested proofs, though. If you need them, either use the optional argument in each nested proof or you have to resort to a more complex patch.

```
\documentclass[orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% avoid the silly redefinition done by llncs
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

%% change proof to accept the optional argument
\patchcmd\proof{proofname}{genericproofname}{}{}
\let\llncsproof\proof
\renewcommand{\proof}[1][\proofname]{\def\genericproofname{#1}\llncsproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:ex}
A very important result.
\end{theorem}

Some comments here \ldots

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:ex}]
It follows by inspection.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I showed also how to avoid the warning about `\vec` given by the `llncs` package when `amsmath` is properly loaded: just load also `bm`, tell the class to keep the original `\vec` and then change it in a much better way than `llncs` does.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option provided via a newly-defined `proof*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{proof*}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\proofname}{#1}%
   \begin{proof}}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:ex}
A very important result.
\end{theorem}

Some comments here \ldots

\begin{proof*}{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:ex}}
It follows by inspection.
\end{proof*}

\end{document}
```

`proof*` takes a single, mandatory argument that internally (temporarily) redefined `\proofname`.